# how to debug Clojure file with arg list

Tags: debugging, clojure

I am new to Clojure and want to debug a Clojure file abc.clj that will take user arguments. To run the file, i will do

```
lein run [arg1 arg2 ..]
```

I have tried emacs-cider and lighttable, but haven't found a way to input user argument from the beginning.

Comment: Could you give an example file?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try the [Debux library](https://github.com/philoskim/debux), and use your REPL to observe results. Seems to me that Clojure is really about the REPL and interactive development.

If I understand what you're trying to do, you should be able to sprinkle debug macros (`dbg`) throughout your code, then run your code with whatever changes to your args. The various results from the `dbg` macros will show in your REPL. I'm not sure if you can do this straight from lein, however.

From the [README](https://github.com/philoskim/debux) page:

> **Basic usage**
>
> This is a simple example. The macro dbg prints an original form and
>   pretty-prints the evaluated value on the REPL window. Then it returns
>   the value without interfering with the code execution.
>
> If you wrap the code with dbg like this,
>
> `(* 2 (dbg (+ 10 20))) ; => 60`
>
> the following will be printed in the REPL window.
>
> REPL output:
>
> `dbg: (+ 10 20) =>   30`